# .sh file returned file path instead of file name

Tags: bash, glob, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am writing a .sh file to print the file names one by one. I have installed ubuntu in windows 10 and using the windows command prompt for executing below code. It is returning "E:/Official/Backups/GGG/*" instead of file names inside. I have also changed the EOL conversion to Unix(LF) by using notepad ++. please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
folder="E:/Official/Backups/GGG"
for entry in "$folder"/*
do
echo "$entry"
done
```

Running the script outputs:

```
$ bash test1.sh
E:/Official/Backups/GGG/*
```

Output of echo $-

```
himBHs
```

Output of ls -ld E:/Official/Backups/GGG

```
ls: cannot access 'E:/Official/Backups/GGG': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please add output of `echo $-` to your question.

Comment: This is not fetching file names inside the directory.

Comment: Please add output of `ls -ld E:/Official/Backups/GGG` to your question.

Comment: Out of interest: Is `E:` just a linux directory/link with an unusual name or does your WSL bash recognize actual windows paths (with `/` instead of `\ `)? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: Nevermind, I think your problem is that you used the windows path without thinking about it; see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bash in WSL does not recognize windows paths. If I want to access `E:\Official\Backups\GGG` I would have to use `/mnt/e/Official/Backups/GGG`.

I assume, the same goes for your WSL bash. Therefore the "path" `E:/Official/Backups/GGG` is just a non-existing directory and your observed behavior is to be expected. With `bash`'s default settings a `*` just stays there as a literal if the directory does not exist or is empty. Example:

```
$ echo /dir/that/doesnt/exist/*
/dir/that/doesnt/exist/*
$ echo /dir/that/exists/but/is/empty/*
/dir/that/exists/but/is/empty/*
$ echo /dir/*
/dir/file1 /dir/file2 /dir/file3 ...
```

Comment: Yes. As you mentioned it is working after using "/mnt/e/Official/Backups/GGG" path. But it is returned path and file name /mnt/e/Official/Backups/GGG/CIH Build script.sql. How to get file name alone ?

Comment: Hem. last sample could render: `/dir/that/does/exist/and/is/not/empty/file1 /dir/that/does/exist/and/is/not/empty/file2 /dir/that/does/exist/and/is/not/empty/file3 ...`

Comment: @ThangarajJ `cd /your/dir` then `for entry in *` or use `basename "$entry"`. Search for it -- this should be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

GGG folder is not exists. Please check and update with valid folder and try again.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

folder="E:"
for entry in "$folder"/*
do
echo "$entry"
done